"client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe" error when trying to log as root with public key authentication
I want to log in as root user using publickey authentication to my OpenSSH server configured that way:
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only
StrictModes no
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Because I cannot send the public key to the server directly, I used another user to do it and to copy the public key into the root directory:
$ssh-copy-id -i /tmp/root_keys john@172.17.0.5
$ssh john@172.17.0.5
$ su root
root@36ba846e6b62:/home/john# mv .ssh/authorized_keys ~/.ssh/
root@36ba846e6b62:/home/john# chown root:root ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
root@36ba846e6b62:/home/john# chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
root@36ba846e6b62:/home/john# ls -la ~/.ssh
total 4
drwx------ 1 root root  30 Apr  6 16:01 .
drwx------ 1 root root  38 Apr  6 12:05 ..
-rw------- 1 root root 567 Apr  6 16:00 authorized_keys

We can see that the file authorized_keys is correctly copied into the root directory with the correct permissions. However, if I try to log in with root, I have an error:
$ssh -i /tmp/root_keys root@172.17.0.5 id
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe

Did I make a mistake somewhere?
Note: if I set the option PermitRootLogin to yes and that I copy the key pair directly in the root ssh folder, it works correctly.

Reproduction steps
I used a Docker container to do this. Here is the Dockerfile used:
FROM debian

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server

# "john" user has the password "john"
RUN useradd -m john
RUN echo "john:pass" | chpasswd

# "mary" user has no password
RUN useradd -m mary
RUN passwd -d mary

# The password of the root user is "root"
RUN echo "root:root" | chpasswd

EXPOSE 22

CMD ["service", "ssh", "start", "-D"]

To build it:
docker build -t ssh_default_configuration default_configuration

Then, I have the sshd_config in a separate file:
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only
StrictModes no
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Then, to run the server:
docker run -d -v sshd_config:/etc/ssh/sshd_config ssh_default_configuration

The command I used to generate the key pair is:
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 3072 -f /tmp/root_keys -N ""

